# Desync with data in store react redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have flatlist with clickable components in it. After click on these components, I dispatch addPhotoToQueue. And than I call _addPhoto on click in flatlist. Let's say I count how many times these clickable components have been clicked. Right after dispatch I console.log data. On the first click value is: 0 (should be 1), on the second click value is: 1 (should be 2) and so on. What am I missing?

This is my image component inside FlatList

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addPhotoToQueue: (uri) => {
      dispatch(addPhotoToQueue(uri))
    },
  };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    queuedPhotos: state.photo.queuedPhotos,
  }
}

class FlatListImage extends React.PureComponent {
  _addPhoto = () => {
    this.props.addPhotoToQueue()
    console.log('how many times I clicked: ', this.props.queuedPhotos)
}
```

This is my Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  queuedPhotos: 0,
};

const PhotoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PHOTO_TO_QUEUE:
        return {
          ...state,
          queuedPhotos: state.queuedPhotos + 1
        }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default PhotoReducer;
```

I expect the console.log will log me correct value right after dispatch.

Comment: Because rendering and updates like that aren't synchronous.
You sould wait until your component has received the new props before you try to log them (in one of the lifecycle methods, for example).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Is there any method that is called right after my component recive new props?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.
Your new props should be available in the next render, and the didUpdate after that render.

If you just want to check whether the change comes true, and render new content accordingly, then render is the place to go.
If you want to invoke some side effects, you'll have to use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle, though to be honest, you migth as well just do it in your click-handler as well then.

Comment: Let's say I want to change the screen after 2 clicks. Checking in _addPhoto wasn't an option. I will check if componentDidUpdate works for me.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, sorry for a basic question and thank you for patience :D If it's the best way to check what I want to check that's all that I wanted to know.

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck, mang.